# What does + mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does the `+` in this CSS rule mean?

```css
h2 + p { 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777; 
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

That means the selector `h2 + p` only selects the `p` that comes **immediately after** an `h2`.

An illustration:

```html
<h2>Headline!</h2>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>  <!-- Selected [1] -->
<p>The second paragraph.</p> <!-- Not selected [2] -->

<h2>Another headline!</h2>
<blockquote>
    <p>A quotation.</p>      <!-- Not selected [3] -->
</blockquote>
```

What's selected and what's not:

1. **Selected**
   This `p` comes right after the first `h2`.
2. **Not selected**
   This `p` occurs after the first `p` as opposed to the `h2`. Since it doesn't immediately follow the `h2`, it's not selected.

   However, since it still follows the `h2` element, just not immediately, the selector `h2 + p` won't match this element, but `h2 ~ p` will, using the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) instead.
3. **Not selected**
   This `p` is located within a `blockquote`, and there's no `h2` before it inside the quote to satisfy its selector.

Answer (score 4):

It selects all `p` elements that are directly *after* a `h2` element in the DOM. Thus, the following `p` element would be styled:

```html
<h2>A heading</h2>
<p>This paragraph will be styled.</p>
```

But this wouldn't:

```html
<h2>A heading</h2>
<hr>
<p>This paragraph will NOT be styled.</p>
```

And neither would this:

```html
<p>This paragraph will NOT be styled.</p>
<h2>A heading</h2>
```

...or this:

```html
<h2>A heading</h2>
<section>
    <p>This paragraph will NOT be styled.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

it selects all P tags that are directly beside an h2 tag.  Then gives it the said attributes.

Comment: Directly *after*, even. And CSS applies to elements, not tags.

Comment: This answer is ambiguous. It will select one P element (not all) that comes directly after a H2 element.

Answer (score 0):

Only affects first p which is **directly following (comes directly after)** the H2

example 1:

```
<h2></h2>
<p></p> <!-- THIS ONE IS AFFECTED -->
<p></p> <!-- THIS ONE IS NOT AFFECTED -->
<p></p> <!-- NOR THIS ONE -->
<p></p> <!-- NOR THIS ONE -->
<p></p> <!-- ETC -->
```

example 2:

```
<h2></h2>
<div></div>
<p></p> <!-- THIS ONE IS NOT AFFECTED -->
```