# What does "+" do in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does + mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382078/what-does-mean-in-css)

I don't understand what the "+" does in this context.

```
.test ul li:hover + li a img {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means any `li` immediatly following a `li:hover`.

See [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) on W3.

> E + F:    Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

And:

> Thus, the following rule states that when a `P` element immediately follows a `MATH` element, it should not be indented:
>
> math + p { text-indent: 0 }