# > and ~ expressions in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the purpose of ~ and > in CSS? For example what does the following expression mean?

```
:checked ~ label ~ .content > *
```

Comment: I recommend you read this article, is very useful: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: That article is fantastic. Well worth bookmarking.

Comment: Has a couple of mistakes, though. The `*` section calls the descendant selector a child selector (but correctly labels it in its own section), and it calls `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes when it later uses the CSS3 pseudo-element notation for `::first-line` and `::first-letter` (?!).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it/4459872

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your selector means:

> Select any element
>   that is a child of an element with the class `content`
>   which follows a `label`
>   which in turn follows a `:checked` input element.

`>` is the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). It selects elements that are children of a certain parent element. Unlike the space (the descendant combinator), it only selects immediately-nested elements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225905/106224) for an illustration on how it works.

`~` is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). It selects elements that follow after other elements within the same parent (i.e. are siblings). Unlike `+` (the adjacent sibling combinator), it doesn't require an element to immediately follow another in the same parent. Compare the illustration below to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382096/106224) which covers the `+` combinator.

Be careful, as the `~` combinator does not just select *any* sibling element. It only selects an element that comes **after** its sibling, so `:checked ~ label` will not match a `label` that occurs before the checked input element.

An illustration:

```html
<section>
    <input type="radio" name="example1" value="1" checked>
    <label>1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example1" value="2">
    <label>2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example1" value="3">
    <label>3</label>

    <div class="content">
        <h3>Subheading 1</h3>     <!-- [1] Selected -->
        <p>Some text              <!-- [1] Selected -->
           <em>with emphasis</em> <!-- [2] Not selected -->
        </p>
        <p>Some text</p>          <!-- [1] Selected -->
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <input type="radio" name="example2" value="1">
    <label>1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example2" value="2">
    <label>2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example2" value="3">
    <label>3</label>

    <div class="content">
        <h3>Subheading 1</h3>     <!-- [3] Not selected -->
        <p>Some text              <!-- [3] Not selected -->
           <em>with emphasis</em> <!-- [2] Not selected -->
        </p>
        <p>Some text</p>          <!-- [3] Not selected -->
    </div>
</section>
```

What's selected and what's not:

1. **Selected**
   This `h3` or `p` element is located directly inside a `.content` parent element. That `.content` element follows at least one `label`, and this `label` occurs after at least one input element that is `:checked`.

   Note that *any* of the radio buttons here can be checked, and the elements will match, because as mention above `~` doesn't require a label to follow it immediately. Also, given the structure, either one of the `~` selectors can be swapped out for a `+`:

   ```
   :checked + label ~ .content > *
   :checked ~ label + .content > *
   ```

   But this selector:

   ```
   :checked + label + .content > *
   ```

   Will only match if the **third** radio button is checked, because it's the only one that's **immediately** followed by a `label` and the `.content` element.
2. **Not selected**
   This `em` element is nested within one of the `p` elements which is itself contained within `.content`. Based on the illustration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225905/106224), it won't be selected as it's not a child of `.content`.
3. **Not selected**
   Unlike in [1], none of the `label` elements in this section follow any `:checked` input element. Therefore, nothing is selected here, because it doesn't satisfy `:checked ~ label`.

Comment: Good answer. Note that reading this top-to-bottom is analogous to *reading the selector right-to-left*.

Comment: @Jeroen: Yep, I link to another example in [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/8842448). And thanks, I've also souped it up with an illustration, which I used to do and miss doing so, so much!

Answer (score 6):

Cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/:

> `E ~ F`   an F element preceded by an E element
>   `E > F`   an F element child of an E element

Answer (score 2):

`:checked` is a pseudo class for radio buttons or checkboxes http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked

`~` is the general sibling selector

`:checked ~ label` selects the label that comes after a selected checkbox or radio button (there can be any number of elements between the two, but they are on the same level and the label comes after the selected checkbox or radio button)

`:checked ~ label ~ .content` selects an element which had the class content and comes after the label described above (again, there can be any number of elements between them)

`>` is the child selector http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

`:checked ~ label ~ .content > *` selects any child of the element described above

Answer (score 1):

`*` all elements
`:checked` input checked status
`.` class name
`>` under element

http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

This page will be useful for you