# Changing color on <a> inside <div> when radio button is checked?

Tags: css, input, css-selectors, checked

http://jsfiddle.net/anvhw/1/

I'm having some trouble trying to change a property on the `<a>` tag when the first radio button is checked. It works fine when I want to change a `<label>` property when one is checked but not with the `<a>`

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The `+` selector means there must not be any other elements coming between the two elements. The reason `+ label` works is because your `label` comes immediately after your radio button. However, that `label` is standing between your radio button and the `div`, so `#radio-one:checked + div` won't work.

You need to use

```
#radio-one:checked + label + div a
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/anvhw/4)

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382078/what-does-mean-in-css/3382096#3382096) for an illustration on how the `+` selector works.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the + could be used to affect any element in parallel.

Comment: @james: That would be `~`, but even then it doesn't affect elements occurring *before* another element, only after. Also, if you had an extra `div` after `#radio-two`, that would be changed by `#radio-one ~ div` unless you have a `#radio-two ~ div` in your CSS as well. It's quite confusing in words, though, so here's [another illustration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737114/and-expressions-in-css/10737139#10737139).

Comment: Right okay thanks. Also the updated fiddle you made seems to change the <a> color when either of the radio buttons are checked. Or rather when 'radio-one' is checked, it doesn't go back to the original when it becomes unselected. Any ideas?

Comment: @james: Uh oh. Looks like WebKit is bugging out. It works for me in other browsers, but I'm seeing the link stay red in Safari.

Comment: Hmm works fine in FF, I may have to use JavaScript instead to achieve the same effect.