# Target body with sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

I have a HTML page with contents (div, h1, ...). With interaction on one of these contents I would like to affect my body. I look at ~ and + sibling symbol for CSS but without success.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS provides nothing that allows you to modify an element based on its children or elements that follow it.

You'll need to look to JavaScript for that.

Comment: You're wrong about the second part. You have `~` and `+` for preceding elements before and after accordingly. You are correct about the fact that you can't "modify an element based on its children". http://generaldisarray.wordpress.com/2006/05/02/introduction-to-css-combinators/

Comment: @iMoses — No. `A+B` selects `B` if the immediately previous sibling was `A`. `A~B` selects `B` if any previous sibling was `A`. `B` must be **after** `A`. Neither of them select an element because something follows it.

Comment: What do you mean by "something follows it". perhaps I don't understand you correctly. "immediately previous sibling" - doesn't it means that B follows A. I agree about the "immediately" part, but it still follows.

Comment: @iMoses — B follows A and you are selecting B not A. You can select an element based on what the element you are selecting follows. You can't select an element based on what follows the element you are selecting.

Comment: @iMoses: Some illustrations... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382078/what-does-mean-in-css/3382096#3382096 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737114/and-expressions-in-css/10737139#10737139