# Unsure functionality of css with checked inputs

Tags: html, css, input, click, label

I was trying to make a css only clicking navigation system using checkboxes and labels.
I never played much around labels and checkboxes other than what they're meant to be used for by the w3c.
This is the minimal code I managed to put this into:

```css
.bar{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.bar ul{
  display:none;
}
.bar input[type=checkbox]{
  display:none;
}
label:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  color:blue;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + ul{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class=bar>
    <li>
      <input type=checkbox id=1><label for=1>about</label>
      <ul>
        <li>us
        <li>you
        <li>cheese
      </ul>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

By clicking on "about" you can see that the label successfully turns blue, but the `ul` right below it in the code doesn't get it's `inline` display, it stays with a display of none as specified on the 4th line of css, which I used to hide the tabs by default.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Use general sibling combinator `~` instead. Like so `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul` or adjacent sibling combinator `+` two times: `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do/10782072#10782072 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382078/what-does-mean-in-css/3382096#3382096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code --> [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ywny19/42/)

Remember that `+` works only if `ul` is first sibling of your `input`. In your case first sibling is `label` so it doesn't work with `ul`. To get this work simply use something like this :

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `~` operator in the last css rule instead of `+`; as shown below. See [The CSS Tricks Article](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) for more details on that.

```css
.bar{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.bar ul{
  display:none;
}
.bar input[type=checkbox]{
  display:none;
}
label:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  color:blue;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class=bar>
    <li>
      <input type=checkbox id=1><label for=1>about</label>
      <ul>
        <li>us
        <li>you
        <li>cheese
      </ul>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope that helps :)